# Relationship between LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, orm

My understanding so far is :

Entity Framework make it easier to use LINQ to SQL. It generate the entity types for us automatically.

I just started to learn LINQ. So the above statement is very likely to be wrong. Could you share your thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relationship between Entity Framework and Linq to Sql.  They're two totally different technologies.

Entity Framework is more advanced, and requires a bit more knowledge to get up to speed than Linq to SQL.

Linq to SQL is no longer being updated by Microsoft, and their forward direction is Entity Framework.  however Linq to SQL is still supported.

Comment: Thanks. This is kind of out of my expectation. I see they share some similar concepts such as *abstract a thin object layer over the physical data store*. So any difference between them?

Comment: @smwikipedia - Yes, they are completely different technologies, that just do similar things.  They are very different in how they work internally, and significant changes in how you utilized them.